# Wrong datetime format in HttpCookie .NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.8

I upgraded a API from .net 4.5 to 4.8. In one endpoint a set a cookie like:

```
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, value)
                {
                    Expires = new DateTimeOffset(validUntilDate).DateTime,
                    Domain = "." + this.Request.RequestUri.Host,
                    Path = "/",
                    Secure = true,
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
                };

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

The problem is that the cookie is never stored in the browser and never sent in subsequent calls to the api.

Looking closer in the browser I see that the datetime format for the cookie is different now:
`Set-Cookie: key=value; domain=.sub.mydomain.se; expires=Thu, 25-Jan-2024 09:05:54 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`

Note the dashes in the date. Correct header should be:
`Set-Cookie: key=value; domain=.sub.mydomain.se; expires=Thu, 25 Jan 2024 09:05:54 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`

I tried to set the correct header `Set-Cookie: key=value; ...` "by hand" by `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie",... )` and it all works fine with correct GMT datetime format, without dashes.

Is it a bug?